# Send message to all connected web socket clients

Tags: java, websocket

I'm using [Jooby](http://jooby.org)'s MVC routes for an API. I have also set up a websocket, to which a few clients connect. What I'm trying to do is send a message to all connected websocket clients whenever a specific http request is received in the server. This is how my route method looks like:

```
@Path("/player")
@Produces("application/json")
public class PlayerRoute {

    @POST
    public Result newPlayer(Request req, @Body Player player) {
        //do some process here

        //this is what I'm trying to achieve..
        allWebsocketSessions.foreach(session ->
                session.send("a new player has been created")
        );

        return Results.ok();
    }
}
```

I've read jooby's documentation but can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can subscribe all users to topic and send message to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems for "session you can call "set" and "get" methods only. Method "send" you can call for "response".